# ScrollableCursor from EclipseLink throws SQLException: The result set is closed. on remote env

Tags: java, jboss, eclipselink

I have problem with ScrollableCursor. On my local environment it works well but on remote env I got exception:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: The result set is closed.
>   Error Code: 0
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1620)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ScrollableCursor.getPosition(ScrollableCursor.java:251)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ScrollableCursor.retrieveNextObject(ScrollableCursor.java:551)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ScrollableCursor.loadNext(ScrollableCursor.java:411)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ScrollableCursor.hasNext(ScrollableCursor.java:277)

My query:

```
private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT"
        + " new MyObjectDto(object.id, object.time)"
        + " FROM ObjectEntity object"
        + " WHERE object.msgDateTime < :startDateTime ";


@Override
    public ScrollableCursor getScrollableCursor(LocalDateTime startDateTime) {
        TypedQuery<ScrollableCursor> query = createQuery(SELECT_QUERY, ScrollableCursor.class)
                .setParameter("startDateTime", startDateTime)
                .setHint(QueryHints.SCROLLABLE_CURSOR, HintValues.TRUE);

        return  query.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Could you please give me some ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by local and remote? Do you have anything in the middle in the non-working situation that might close connections, like a firewall, or code that is closing the connection underneath the cursor?

Comment: By local I meant my own JBoss server, by remote I meant JBoss server which is running for test team. I assume that there could be difference between configuration but I couldn't catch anything. No, I don't have any code. I assume that somehow ResultSet is closed automatically.